# What is the purpose of the bitwise XOR operator in this C++ application?

Tags: serial-port, c++-cli, xor, .net

I'm using System::IO::Ports for a project that requires sending data over a serial port and I'm not sure why the "^" operator is being used on my data types.

For instance, take this code snippet:

`SerialPort^ serialPort = gcnew SerialPort();`

`array<String^>^ serialPorts = SerialPort::GetPortNames();`

Now what exactly is the purpose of the caret operator here? I know what an exclusive or operation is, but I don't see how it applies in this instance. What are the strings being XOR'd with?

I tried to search for the answer to this, but every answer deals with a description of what XOR logic is, not how it's used in a circumstance like this.

The code works, I'm just asking from a curiosity standpoint. If anyone happens to know the answer, throw me a reply and I'll give you a mad high-five

Comment: This is not C++, but this thing called [C++/CLI](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: It's a handle, i.e. a glorified pointer. gcnew allocates memory that can be collected by a garbage collector, so you cannot use a raw pointer to refer to it.

Comment: @DanielFrey what is the appropriate tag *c++cli*?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer on MSDN: 

"The handle declarator (^, pronounced "hat"), modifies the type specifier to mean that the declared object should be automatically deleted when the system determines that the object is no longer accessible."

Now I'm still not sure why this is used vs. standard garbage collection or why you can't, for instance, use cout << [Some String^];

EDIT: Thank you, faranwath. That's a good answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour "c++-cli"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT `XOR`. Its Microsofts spin on C++(C++/CLI). The `String^` represents [system::string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) which is different than `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an XOR. This is C++/CLI code and `T^` (for any .NET reference type `T`) is a "handle" or managed reference.